# Does Dispatcher.Invoke call CheckAccess internally?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, inotifycollectionchanged

I have a custom concurrent observable collection that I'm using as an `ItemsSource` in a WPF desktop application.

For the collection to be "oberservable" I implemented `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Since it is "concurrent", i.e. can be modified from multiple threads, I'm invoking the `CollectionChanged` event using `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher` (as suggested by the docs).

Because I want the UI elements to be updated live, e.g. re-sort the list when a property changes, (a.k.a. "live shaping"), I also implemented a `ICollectionViewFactory` to create the required view with its settings, e.g. `SortDescriptions`.

Consider the following code flow - all on the UI/dispatcher thread:

- I create the collection.
- I add items and raise the according`CollectionChanged` events.
- I load a `Window` with a `ListBox` and bind it to the collection.

I have three versions of a function which is called whenever the internal list (of my custom collection) is changed:

**Version 1** (with `CheckAccess` and `InvokeAsync`)

```
    private void _notify(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (_dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
        }
        else
        {
            _dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, args));
        }
    }
```

**Version 2** (without `CheckAccess` and `InvokeAsync`)

```
    private void _notify(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        _dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, args));
    }
```

**Version 3** (without `CheckAccess` and `Invoke`)

```
    private void _notify(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        _dispatcher.Invoke(() => CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, args));
    }
```

Version 1 & 3 work fine, but in Version 2 all items are displayed twice in the ´ListBox`.

It appears to be something like this:

- If I'm on the UI thread and I call `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`, the call is added to "the end of the UI message pump" - without the thread waiting for the result.
- The UI element binds itself to the collection, creates the view and fills it's inner source with the added items.
- "Later", then, when the message pump is further processed, the dispatched events are raised and listened to and the `CollectionView` adds the items to its source, creating the duplicate entries.

And I (think I) understand that in Version 1 the events are fired (and waited for) before the UI element exists, so there are no issues regarding the `CollectionView`.

But why/*how* does Version 3 (with `Invoke`) work? The way the code behaves differently than when using `InvokeAsync` makes me think that it should dead-lock, because it waits for a call that should be processed "further down its own message pump", but it obviously doesn't. Does `Invoke` internally do some kind of `CheckAccess`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Dispatcher.Invoke call CheckAccess internally?

Yes it can, you can find the details [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/windowsbase/R/4990431309c71f1a.html)

```
public void Invoke(Action callback, DispatcherPriority priority, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan timeout)
{
   if(callback == null)
   {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("callback");
   }
   ValidatePriority(priority, "priority");

   if( timeout.TotalMilliseconds < 0 &&
       timeout != TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1))
   {
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("timeout");
   }

   // Fast-Path: if on the same thread, and invoking at Send priority,
   // and the cancellation token is not already canceled, then just
   // call the callback directly.
   if(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && priority == DispatcherPriority.Send && CheckAccess())
```